# Disable search for the products on the Hybris front end having a specific attribute value

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Suppose I have a requirement whereby I don't want to search the products on the `Hybris` frontend having a specific attribute value. Even if the following products are present in the Hybris `SOLR index`.

How to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

Which products should be indexed are defined by flexible search queries.

You find them in `hmc/backoffice` by navigating to `System/Facet Search/Indexed Types`. Select your indexed type. There you find full and update queries.

The full query is used by a `Full SolR Indexer CronJob` which runs in the default case every night and recreates the SolR index completely. The update query similarly is used by a `Update SolR Indexer CronJob` which runs by default every hour and just updates products which have been changed in between. Therefore you find something like `WHERE {sl:modifiedtime} >= ?lastIndexTime` in the update query, which is missing in the full query.

You can change the query in every way you need it. E.g. assuming your query is:

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Product}
```

change it to

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} WHERE {myAttribute} LIKE 'index this product'
```

PS: Find the `Solr Indexer Cronjobs` on your associated Facet Search Config (`System/Facet Search/Facet Search Config`).

PPS: There is also a delete query, where you define products which should be removed from `SolR` index.

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but I think that the problem here is products are already in the Index, and may be we want to use them in other research options.

Comment: @johannesNolte,will the listener concept be better here?

Comment: @Nomade When you have products in the index, that you don't want to have there anymore, just run a Full SolR Indexer Cronjob, and everything will be removed from the index and all products from your full query will be added to it. When your query excludes products you don't want in your index, they will be gone after a full indexing.

Comment: @Rachit I am not familiar with the listener concept. Can you give me more information?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to achieve product visibility on front-end using Solr.

**1. Index only those products what you need. As said by @Johannes Nolte, Adjust Full and Update Index Query**

The problem here is this way completely remove products from search. If there is a requirement where you need to show/hide products based on some other attribute, you can't do it.

Other way is

**2. Add Search Filter before hitting actual Solr Query to Solr Server**

Suppose you want to show/hide product based on productType (Type A & Type B)

User 1 is eligible to see Type A product, User 2 is eligible to see Type B product.

You need to first index your productType attribute and make it facet=true. Make sure you select visible=false so that this attribute should not be visible in facet on storefront.

See OOTB SearchFiltersPopulator class, you will get an idea how we can add dynamic filter in Solr query before sending to Solr Server for search.

Similarly You can create your own filterPopulator e.g. **MySearchFiltersPopulator** which contains your custom visibility logic.

```
if Current_User is User 1
  target.getSearchQuery().addFacetValue("productType", "Type A");
else Current_User is User 2
  target.getSearchQuery().addFacetValue("productType", "Type B");
```

Finally add custom populator in `commerceSearchQueryPageableConverter` chain.

```
<bean parent="modifyPopulatorList">
    <property name="list" ref="commerceSearchQueryPageableConverter" />
    <property name="add" ref="mySearchFiltersPopulator" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.I had one query:Can a SearchRestriction be useful here?

Comment: SearchRestriction won't work i guess in Solr. Just check at the time of Full Indexing whether query is affecting by search restriction.

Comment: Thanks a lot but if the attribute is not a facet,then how do we proceed ahead?