# How to exclude solr facet search results in hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

Hybris 6.5 version

I want to exclude solr facet search results in hybris, I have hidden required facet to exclude the result in facetsearchquerypopulator.java like following
code:

```
for(FacetField facet : facetList) {
  if("price".equals(facet.getField()) && isHidePrices()){
    continue;
  }

  FacetInfo facetInfo = new FacetInfo(facet.getField(), facet.getFacetType());
  facets.put(facet.getField(), facetInfo);
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to achieve? Don't display products that belong to a special facet? Why index them in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036604/disable-search-for-the-products-on-the-hybris-front-end-having-a-specific-attrib/49055361#49055361

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding **buildFacets** method of **SearchResponseFacetsPopulator**

```
    for (final Facet facet : solrSearchResultFacets)
    { 
         if("price".equals(facet.getName()) && isHidePrices()){
          continue;
          }

          ...
          ...
     }
```

Comment: Dear HybrisFreelance,

i am happy your quick response ,my intention is to hide the facet results (products) in category page..

Comment: @Raghu, what about search page ? you want to hide the facet results too ?

Comment: @Raghu better you elaborate your question with some example

Comment: @Nomade ,yes in search page also need to hide the facet result